# Why does the C# "in" keyword worsen performance?

Tags: c#, performance, keyword

I have been testing various ways to improve performance in C#. One of the things that was suggested was using `ref` and `in`, to pass objects by reference instead of by value.

The `ref` keyword worked great! It consistently performed better then the normal function parameters would. However, `in` would consistently perform worse than `ref` or without keywords, at least for the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const int Iterations = 10000000;
        Point3D point = new Point3D(3, 4, 5);

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        // Benchmarking the method that takes the parameter by value
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            ComputeLengthByValue(point);
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time without 'in': {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

        // Benchmarking the method that takes the parameter with the 'in' keyword
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            ComputeLengthByIn(in point);
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time with 'in': {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
      
        // Benchmarking the method that takes the parameter with the 'ref' keyword
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            ComputeLengthByRef(ref point);
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time with 'ref': {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }

    public static double ComputeLengthByValue(Point3D point)
    {
        return point.ComputeLength();
    }

    public static double ComputeLengthByIn(in Point3D point)
    {
        return point.ComputeLength();
    }

    public static double ComputeLengthByRef(ref Point3D point)
    {
        return point.ComputeLength();
    }
}

public struct Point3D
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public double ComputeLength()
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z);
    }
}
```

Here are the results:

| Parameter Keyword | Time |
| --- | --- |
| without 'in' or 'ref' | 11 ms |
| with 'in': | 14 ms |
| with 'ref': | 10 ms |

Why does `in` perform worse? I would expect it to do better then `ref`, because the compiler knows it's not going to be assigned to.

Comment: Hint: see what the compiler does with your code https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkEAbIgCYD2ArgEYA2ApmmQLYAOFALnQDJ0B2A5uwAWAIQCeANQCGNCnQAUABTIBLXu3gARRC1XqAlNlxYYuM8gDsOvewB0qZm048Bw+foDcRnAF9Y3vGQiUkpaBgdWDm4+QVExAEleeTVEZTUNbV10w1NjALMQKyz1e0col1j3L1zffMCCYnJqekZI5xjhcQAlOgAzeQAnPtSbLWtsgJNzXELxkoinaNchKoC/GHXYBEQAZ3YBigBjdhH0rVgpmaQmsMQADWqC69CWgE1Hq5DmhgAtaoDtml1Fp5DcWgAPAA0X1uYmhYIYAC8cmZLtM7ogALyIcEfaavLGIMR48w/QmIkmbGqBBGtRYVNwovLUgpWACyUmEtgAygBHAbseQYgBU90QAGpEATRQTJWTRT9PGtYD4gA

Comment: [`in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier) is **not** for passing by reference.

Comment: Looks at what happen if you change Point3D from struct to class.

Comment: What version of the framework and the compiler are you using. The in version seems to be faster for me

Comment: Also: don't benchmark with stopwatch. Use benchmarkdotnet.

Comment: It's a pleasant surprise that nobody has thrown the link to Eric Lippert's rant in the comments yet.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Read the docs for [`in` Parameter Modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier): *The `in` keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference …*

Comment: *... but ensures the argument is not modified.*

Comment: "Defensive Copies". Read about them [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/avoiding-struct-and-readonly-reference-performance-pitfalls-with-errorprone-net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the `in` keyword is just compiled to the `ref` parameter, but with extra safety steps:

```
// Decompilation of the three methods
public static double ComputeLengthByValue(Point3D point)
{
    return point.ComputeLength();
}

public static double ComputeLengthByIn([In][IsReadOnly] ref Point3D point)
{
    // this line is removed for classes and readonly structs
    Point3D point3D = point;
    return point3D.ComputeLength();
}

public static double ComputeLengthByRef(ref Point3D point)
{
   return point.ComputeLength();
}
```